# Apple Watch scrolling ticker label

Tags: ios, user-interface, apple-watch

Is it possible to add a scrolling ticker text view into an Apple Watch app like this?[image: Ticker text]

Comment: I think you could just use a scrollview with an animated contentOffset to achieve that affect fairly simply.

Comment: Will not be straight forward but should be achievable, yes.

Comment: @Braains WatchKit doesn't include scroll views.

Comment: The Spotify Apple Watch app manages it somehow

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. but there is a work around...

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

@IBOutlet var label: WKInterfaceLabel!

let fullText = "i am  a long text and i am scrollable horizontally lol."
var scrolledText: String?
var timer: NSTimer?

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    scrolledText = fullText
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: Selector("timerDidFire:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    label.setText(scrolledText)
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    timer?.invalidate()
}

func timerDidFire(timer: NSTimer) {
    if scrolledText!.characters.count > 1 {
        scrolledText!.removeAtIndex(scrolledText!.startIndex)
    } else {
        scrolledText = fullText
    }
    label.setText(scrolledText)

    }

}
```

Comment: For better look and feel, you can add some extra white spaces as prefix to your text ....

Comment: Is there any way where we can calculate the number of characters which will fit in one line?